# Animate Pie Chart in Angular

Tags: angular, d3.js

I am trying to do the animate d3 pie chart like this example
 [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Nw62g/1/)

**Angular**

```
  private arc: any;
this.arc = d3
      .arc()
      .outerRadius(this.radius)
      .innerRadius(this.radius * 0.655);
this.slices = this.mainContainer
      .selectAll("path")
      .remove()
      .exit()
      .data(this.pie(this.airline_tonnage))
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .append("path")
      .attr("d", this.arc)
      .attr("fill", (d, i) => this.color(i))
      .transition()
      .ease(d3.easeElasticIn)
      .duration(2000)
      .attrTween("d", function(d) {
        var i = d3.interpolate(d.startAngle + 0.1, d.endAngle);
        return function(t) {
          d.endAngle = i(t);
          return this.arc(d);
        };
      })
      .on("mouseover", function(d) {
        d3.select("#tooltip")
          .style("opacity", 1)
          .select("#value")
          .text(d.value);
      })
      .on("mouseout", function() {
        d3.select("#tooltip").style("opacity", 0);
      });
```

this error I am getting

> ERROR TypeError: this.arc is not a function
>       at SVGPathElement. (forcast.component.ts:564)
>       at SVGPathElement. (attrTween.js:5)

[image]

how I can fix this.

Comment: initialize d3 chart instance

Comment: I didnt get you :@

Comment: `this.arc = d3. this.svg
      .arc()
      .outerRadius(this.radius)
      .innerRadius(this.radius * 0.655);`
this.svg is variable which holds `d3.select("#airlineChart").select("svg")`;

Answer (score 0):

When calling a function that you give it to change a selection, d3 will update the `this` variable to be the DOM element being worked upon, which is why `this` isn't the object you are expecting it to be in your `attrTween` function.

One solution would be to pass a delegate to `attrTween` instead of a function. In fact, you already do something similar (for apparently similar reasons) in your `attr("fill", (d, i) => this.color(i))`. Here, `this` is still the object you expect.

Applying this pattern to your use case, you'll need to use some curly brackets to contain your multi-line delegate, something like:

```
      .attrTween("d", d => {
        var i = d3.interpolate(d.startAngle + 0.1, d.endAngle);
        return function(t) {
          d.endAngle = i(t);
          return this.arc(d);
        };
      })
```